# Elastic Search 6.4 throwing Error upon creating custom character filter

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-analyzers

So I am pretty sure I am missing something in the syntax but i can't seem to figure out what exactly. I am trying to create the phone number pattern capture token filter defined [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-phone-number/32771/3). It says to define a keyword filter and then apply the pattern capture token on top. So that's what I did:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "phone": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_phone_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_phone_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "phone_number"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "char_filter": {
            "phone_number": {
                "type": "pattern_capture",
                "preserve_original": 1,
                "patterns": [
                    "1(\\d{3}(\\d+))"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is causing the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.char_filter.phone_number.patterns] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unknown setting [index.char_filter.phone_number.patterns] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings",
        "suppressed": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.char_filter.phone_number.preserve_original] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            },
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.char_filter.phone_number.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong, That'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link which you've mentioned looks quite old.

The `pattern_capture` no longer applies on [`char_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-charfilters.html) but only on [`token filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-charfilters.html)

Below is how your mapping would be if you are using Elasticsearch above 5.x

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "_doc":{  
         "properties":{  
            "phone":{  
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"my_phone_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "my_phone_analyzer":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"keyword",
               "filter":[  
                  "phone_number"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "phone_number":{  
               "type":"pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original":true,
               "patterns":[  
                  "1(\\d{3}(\\d+))"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can make use of the [`Analyze API`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) in order to see what tokens are generated as mentioned below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_phone_analyzer",
  "text": "19195557321"
}
```

### Tokens:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "19195557321",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "9195557321",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "5557321",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: ha ha you beat me in this , to provide the _analyze api and output :p

Comment: I can't comment here. This doesn't allow me to type what I want to. But didn't realise that you've answered this.

Comment: I wonder, what SO is not allowing you to type, what you want to type :-)

Comment: Something really sensitive and equally funny about me dude  :-)

Comment: This is becoming interesting now, you are creating suspense here :|

Comment: Thank you guys both of you, so much! This was really helpful! Now I need to build on top of what you guys have provided and strip all the useless characters like +-() at search time. I'll get into that myself and hopefully learn in the process. I am going to accept Kamal's answer as it has more information but Amit, your help is equally appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your configuration of creating the `my_phone_analyzer`.

1. `pattern_capture` is allowed in the token filter, not in char filter, read more here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html
2. `preserve_original` setting doesn't take `1` value instead of that it uses `true`, `false` as a value.

So, Considering all these things, I was able to create `my_phone_analyzer` with the same settings of yours.

```
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "code" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : true,
               "patterns": [
                    "1(\\d{3}(\\d+))"
                ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "code" : {
               "tokenizer" : "keyword",
               "filter" : [ "code", "lowercase" ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues.